# D3000: "Error: Turn camera off and then on again." Quick fix?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3000, error

I'm at a friend's beach wedding. I shot a bunch of pictures last night with the kit 18-55 VR lens, then today I used my Vivitar 70-200 AI (non-CPU) lens to shoot pictures on the beach.

When I came inside, I switched back to the kit lens, and the camera gives me the error "Error: Turn camera off and then on again." If I detach the lens and cycle power, it goes away, but immediately returns when I attach the lens.

It also happens when I attach the Nikon 35mm f/1.8 AF-S, which implies that it's the camera.

My battery is low; I've put it on the charger to see if that will help.

I also called Nikon, and they're going to cover it under warranty, but I'd really like to use the camera tonight. Does anyone know of any quick fixes for this problem that might get me through the night?

EDIT:

I have charged the battery, and it's now malfunctioning in a different way: none of the buttons on the side of the display, the D-pad, info button, or the delete button are working. However, it now takes pictures with the kit lens, and I can access the important settings (shutter, aperture, etc.) via the dial and exposure compensation button. Hopefully this will last through tonight, and I'll be able to get *something*.

(Also, for anyone wondering, I am *not* the wedding photographer; just a guest, so this isn't the end of the world.)

EDIT:

Finally got the camera back from Nikon. (They received it Oct 28 - an 11-day turnaround.) The invoice says "RPL MEMORY COMPRESSION". Not sure what memory compression had to do with my issue, but it's fixed (plus the two annoying specks of viewfinder dust are gone.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't the answer that you want to hear, but it sounds like it might be, as they say in technical terms, busted.  Best to get it off to Nikon's repair folks.

Comment: Yep, the camera is going in the mail ASAP. I somehow managed to get some OK shots, though.